# How many milliseconds is a byte of .WAV audio?

Tags: audio, wav

I broke out a .WAV file into a byte array.  The audio is 16 bit, 1 channel, with a sampling rate of 44,100HZ.

Is there a way to calculate what one byte of data represents with respect to time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One byte of 16 bit audio isn't anything.  You need two bytes for a sample at 16-bit.

If you want to know how many milliseconds you have per sample...

```
1,000 (ms) / Frequency (Hz)
```

44.1kHz is ~0.0227ms per sample.

Comment: Awesome.  So for 8 bit audio one byte would be one sample and then the same conversion applies based on frequency?

This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Ron That's correct.  And, don't forget your channel count.  If you have 2 channels, everything doubles.

Comment: Brad, I just realized I should have e-mailed you instead! :)

Comment: @Ron Small world.  :-D

Comment: @brad so if i have a frequency of 48000hz i would have 0.0208333ms per 16 bits (2 bytes)? but what if it is two channel? would that be 0.0208333 per 16 bit @ 2 channel  0.0416666ms? (4 bytes)

Comment: and this would only pertain to the actual audio and not the bytes read in any headers?

Comment: @james28909 Each channel is sampled simultaneously, so the sample rate and duration per sample are essentially two ways of measuring the exact same thing no matter how many channels you have.  Though of course the byte size is multiplied by the number of channels you have.  And yes, these calculations assume raw PCM audio and are ignoring the size of the container.